# What are the downsides of passing a class logger between Classes in Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Let's say I have a Class A that creates a class logger. Then Class A calls an instance of Class B. If I were to pass Class A's logger into Class B and then Class B logs using the parent logger what are the downsides of this?

Or is it purely the prefix of the message is changed and all other functionality is the same as if I would have created a logger for each respective class?

```java
...

public ClassA {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassA.class);

    public ClassA() {
        this.classB = new ClassB(log);
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        classB.noteworthyAction();
    }
}

public ClassB {
    private Logger log;

    public ClassB(Logger log) {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public void noteworthyAction() {
        ...
        log.info("Something happened that was worth logging.");
        ...
    }

}
```

*Note*: this is not a question of how to pass a logger between two classes. I am purely asking from a usability perspective and **if I lose any functionality or risk any errors** using the loggers this way.

To further explain why I am interested in this, let's say two different Classes (ClassA and ClassC, where ClassC is identical to ClassA except with its own logger) call the same class which has an important logging statement. I want ClassA's call to ClassB to log in one appender while ClassC's call to ClassB to log in the other appender.

Comment: a) by having a different Logger, means that you can change the logging level for each Logger (DEBUG, INFO etc).  b) Sharing the same Logger means that you have to pass the variable to the constrcutor, doing away with the default no-arg default constrcutor

Comment: and the logger passed to the constructor uses the 'Class' name in log lines defined in by object that created the passed debugger.